# How to disable map introduction screens (MOTD)?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How can I disable the map introduction screen (MOTD) shown when joining a new server or changing maps?

I've understood that the game ceases using intro when the player has visited a map a specified amount of times (the value is likely high, such as 50).

[image: MOTD screen]

(can require up to three mouse clicks to skip, autoplays video & audio)

Comment: I found file `viewed.res` in `~\Team Fortress 2\tf\media`, I set all values to 50. If that works I'll post an answer. Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/437678-team-fortress-2/61603528

Comment: Doesn't work, but the file doesn't include all maps by default, only those played by the current user. Reinstalling or verifying game cache resets the log it seems.

Comment: Which screen exactly are you talking about?  The screen in the screenshot is the MOTD and it shows every map change.  It's set by the server owner and is sent by the server on every map change.

Comment: @Powerlord: In that case, about MOTD.

Answer (score 2):

The command `cl_disablehtmlmotd 0` disables MOTD. Goes into the console, **but** will only work for unofficial servers and not Valve ones.

Comment: can also be used in `autoexec.cfg`

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `cl_disablehtmlmotd 1`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Source Engine has two types of MOTD: plain text and HTML. If client will choose to disable HTML MOTD, it falls back to plain text.